# Alias a command to run in the background

Tags: bash, alias

I'd like a keyboard shortcut to work as so:

```
> e foo.txt
```

to expand as

```
> emacs foo.txt &
```

It's simple to use `alias e=emacs`, but how do I insert the `&` after the filename? I realize it may not be possible using just `alias`, so I'll accept any bash solution. If a shell script is needed please explain how it works.

Comment: You should use `emacsclient` or `gnuclient` to open a file from command-line instead of opening a new `emacs` for each file: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Alias in bash can't have arguments, but you can use functions.

```
e() { emacs "$@" & }
```

then

```
e foo.txt
```

will do what you want.

Comment: This has a problem when I type `e foo*` in a directory with both `foo.cpp` and `foo.h`, only one of the files will open.

Comment: @Hooked, then use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` in the function.

Comment: @AProgrammer that doesn't seem to work for wildcards. The syntax I'm using is: `emacs $* &` and an even better solution seems to be `e() { command emacs $* & disown }`